# How to integrate third party plugin with AMP

Tags: javascript, jquery, amp-html, intl-tel-input

I am trying to integrate the `intlTelInput` plugin into the AMP page. The plugin is working fine but AMP throwing an error (Custom javascript is not allowed).

**Plugin Info**
https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

For more clarity, I am attaching an error screenshot.

Below is the code snippet.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡ lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-05IkdNHoAlkhrFVUCCN805WC_h4mcI98GUBssmShF2VJAXKyZTrO_TmJ-4eBo0Cy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/css/intlTelInput.css";
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/js/intlTelInput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <section class="todoapp">
    <amp-script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/js/intlTelInput.min.js" layout="container">
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </amp-script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
      window.intlTelInput(input, {
        autoHideDialCode: false,
        geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
          $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
            callback(countryCode);
          });
        },
        initialCountry: "auto",
        nationalMode: false,
      });
    </script>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any better way to use this plugin with AMP Page?

Comment: You have several problems.
1) You can't import styles as you show above.
2) You can't load ajax as a src (for several reasons; one of which is size).
3) the $ reference will fail because of #2.
4) you can't do jsonp - you need to use `amp-state` to initalize reference data.
5) you need to read AMP documentation.

Comment: I read the entire documentation I know I can't use custom javascript but for the requirement, I have to use this jquery plugin anyhow. so if any solution there to use this plugin with amp please suggest it.

Comment: Impossible to use jQuery - it's too large and has non-valid statements. You may be able to isolate the jQuery statements you need and build a valid vanilla JS statement. We've used this successfully: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/replace-jquery